# why do I get an error in this code

Tags: qt, user-interface, qfile

I have looked at several different tutorials and all the code looks the same but when I try to compile it I get two errors. They are no match for call to '(QFile) (QString&)' no match for  call to '(QTextSteam) (Qfile)'. Could you please explain why? The following is part of my code if you need more just ask.

my header chunk of code

```
private:
QLabel *label;
QTextEdit *left;
QTextEdit *right;
QLineEdit *user;
QTextStream file;
QFile namefile;
QString name;
QString n;
```

my source code

```
n ="name.txt";
namefile(n);
if (!namefile.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
{
    return;
}
file(&namefile);
name=file.readLine();
right->setText(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to have more to do with C++ than with Qt.  In particular, it would be worthwhile for you to look into C++ initialization lists, and how class members are constructed in general.

In any event, I am assuming that the code you've listed as "my source code" is in the constructor of a class.  One option is to first re-order the private members such that they are listed in order of initialization:

```
private:
QString n;
QFile namefile;
QTextStream file;
QString name;
```

Then to initialize them in the initialization list of the class constructor:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
   :n("name.txt")
   ,namefile(n)
   ,file(&namefile)
{
   if (!namefile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
   {
      return;
   }

   name = file.readLine();

   // Rest of your code goes here.
}
```

There are other ways of accomplishing this, but I'll leave it to you to research what I've suggested above.

Comment: Thanks have not been doing much object oriented programming until the last few weeks. My instructor is teaching C right now. But we have a competition coming up so I thought it best to use a GUI. Won't learn object oriented until java. So thanks took your advice to.

Comment: It compiles fine but then tells me the program expectantly because of a segmentation fault quit?

Comment: @JustinRolf What does your debugger say?

Comment: @JustinRolf Try doing a full rebuild

Answer (score -1):

Just change

```
file.setDevice(&namefile);
```

Comment: setDevice is not a method of QFile.